# Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 - Blender doesn't start anymore after update on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi, arm, blender, arm64

After initial installation of Ubuntu 21.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 (8 GB version) I was able to start Blender and create a simple project. Now, some system updates later, it doesn't start anymore. Starting Blender from the command line shows following message:

```
Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.
```

How can I check, which system update has changed the OpenGL setting? Is there a way to manually modify this?

Comment: Aside from novelty, what is the point of running Blender on a Raspberry?

Answer (score 0):

Blender has been switched to a newer OpenGL version. The latest version, that supports older GPUs is 2.79. You can grab it here: https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/